# Field type "file" - alt text settings

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I have "Enable custom alternate text" checked. I see the "Alternate Text: " input box in the Drupal admin panel when adding new content, the alt data gets saved into the db, but doesn't show on the front end. Any idea why this could be happening.

Thanks.

Comment: It's been added to the tags. No need to keep adding it the title.

Answer (score 0):

A: The previous developer's theme didn't include the alt tags in the template.